# find the coordinates of the closest point on a cylinder to another point in 3D using lagrange multipliers

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

The cylinder has the equation $y^2 + z^2 = 25$
The point is $(2,9,12)$
How do I find the coordinates of the closest point on the cylinder to the point $(2,9,12)$ using lagrange multipliers?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the point we seek obviously has $x-$coordinate $x=2.$

The function we want to minimize is

$\displaystyle L = (y-9)^2 + (z-12)^2 - \lambda (y^2 + z^2 -25)$.

$\displaystyle0 = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = (y-9) - \lambda y$

$\displaystyle0 = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial L}{\partial z} = (z-12) - \lambda z$

$\displaystyle0 = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = y^2 + z^2 - 25$.

$\Longrightarrow (1 + \lambda)y = 9 \textrm{ and } (1+\lambda ) z = 12,$

$(81 + 144)/(1+\lambda)^2 = 25$

$\Rightarrow \lambda=2  \Rightarrow y=3, z= 4.$